# Is it possible to add a keyfile to a veracrypt system partition

Tags: veracrypt

I would like to be able to backup the veracrypt system partition from linux, but don't want to type a password. Is it possible to add a keyfile in addition to the password for the system partition?

Comment: No, system partition doesn't support keyfile. BTW, could you clarify how it possible: "add a keyfile in addition to the password" and "don't want to type a password". To me it sounds like  "Give me a candy, but don't give me a candy"

Comment: No, because I consider the partition to contain data that can either  be accessed from the OS or from another OS. So if can open the container using cryptsetup in linux, I want another way of opening this using say a key file which can contain more entropy etc and need no be stored in say a script. With luks you can add keys to slots that are either passwords or keyfiles. It doesn't care.

Comment: I know about LUKS, but it isn't a case for veracrypt. It support keyfile with file base container only

Answer (score 1):

## No

As a rule, system partitions in Veracrypt don't support keyfiles.

And Even if they did, it wouldn't be possible do do what you are trying:

Unlike LUKS, which has several different slots that all contain the encrypted master key and just requires you to provide the key for one of them - be it in the form of a password or a keyfile - Veracrypt only has one encrypted instance of the master key. To decrypt this, it requires either a password or a keyfile or both - it doesn't have LUKS's capability of providing several different methods to unlock a given volume at the same time.

So even if you somehow managed to add a keyfile to your system partition, you would also have to provide said file every time you want to boot Windows. And if you also removed the password to automate access via the keyfile from Linux, you also wouldn't be required to enter it at boot anymore, either.